# Occasional Unsatisfied-link errors after release

Tags: android, java-native-interface

My app is unsing JNI. I released it a few weeks ago. Through the crash report lib I use I notice occasional "Unsatisfied link" crashes. This crashes occur roughly 1 time all 100 installations.

One was

*"Couldn't load jsqlite: findLibrary returned null"*.
The other was a plain unsatisfied link error as if the jni method would not be there.

What I notice that in the APK the native libs are in the "lib" folder whereas they are in the "libs" folder in my development environment.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should put the native Libs in `lib` folder in your Project and then re-import the native libs.
The crash will hopefully get resolved this way.

Comment: But in the apk they are in the lib folder. Everything runs fine on 99% of the devices.

Comment: Please specify the devices on which, your app is getting crashed.

Comment: Eidolon15 Nand Gb2, Samsung GT S5690, and most disturbingly on an I9300 (S3). But 25% of my clients are running on the S3 without problems.